# Firestore: How to update an existing field

Tags: database, firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update a Firestore document field I have set earlier through REST API.

I have a document (users) which contains all user data. Now I like to be able to update the field 'testfield' - which is part of this user data - through REST API.

I have sent a HTTP POST Request to 
`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[MY_PROJECT_ID]/databases/(default)/documents/users?documentId=-example`

with request body

```
{
    "fields": {
        "testfield": {
            "booleanValue": true
        }
    }
}
```

All I get by now is an error message telling me that the document already exists, what I know, since I am trying to update this document.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Firestore REST API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/), you use a PATCH request to update a field.

A POST isn't going to work, since that's used for creating new documents. That explains the error that the document already exists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I knew that website, but did not understand it. 
Now I got the solution:

You have to send a HTTP PATCH request to https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[MY_PROJECT_ID]/databases/(default)/documents/[DOCUMENT_PATH]?updateMask.fieldPaths=[FIELD_NAME] with request body {
 "name": "projects/[MY_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/users/-example/",
    "fields": {
        "testfield": {
            "booleanValue": true
        }
    }
}